# Logs and ELK stack on separate servers, how to display the logs?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, visualization, elastic-stack

I have logs on one server and ELK stack -- ElasticSearch, Kibana, Logstash -- on another. I want to display  the logs, which are on the 1st server, in Kibana, which is on the 2nd one.

How can I do that? Is  logstash capable of retrieving logs over the internet from a remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use Filebeat on server one and send the logs to the logstash server.

https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat

Comment: is that the simplest solution?  Is logstash capable of retrieving logs over the internet from a remote server?

Comment: I think it is the easiest solution, there are other options like using sockets, or syslog. But most of them are using push from the app server and not pull from the elk server. You can find all possible inputs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html

Comment: doesn't filebeat send logs directly to elastic_search, not to logstash?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/config-filebeat-logstash.html

Answer (score 0):

Logstash can't access remote file, you'll have to use a shipper, like beaver, using udp or tcp transport:
[Beaver documentation](https://python-beaver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/usage.html#shipping-to-a-broker).

Comment: This just doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @merinoff Happy now?